# Failing to get ids from kivy object

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to use ids with `ObjectProperty()` but doesn't work like think. The way I understand ObjectProperty is `variablename = ObjectProperty()` as a reference to a class in the .kv file named variablename but I have misunderstood something because I get the following error: `swiper_manager = MySwiperManager.ids.swiper_manager
 AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'ids'`.

.py file

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.uix.managerswiper import MDSwiperPagination
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

Builder.load_file("Prelogin/prescreenmanger.kv")

class MySwiperManager(BoxLayout):
    pass

class PreScreenManager(Screen):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Indigo'
    MySwiperManager = ObjectProperty()
    swiper_manager = MySwiperManager.ids.swiper_manager
    paginator = MDSwiperPagination()
    paginator.screens = swiper_manager.screen_names
    paginator.manager = swiper_manager
    swiper_manager.paginator = paginator
    MySwiperManager.add_widget(paginator)
```

.kv file

```
<ScreenOne@Screen>:
    name: 'screen one'
    Label: 
        text: 'Hello World'

<ScreenTwo@Screen>:
    name: 'screen two'


<ScreenThree@Screen>:
    name: 'screen three'


<ScreenFour@Screen>:
    name: 'screen four'



<ScreenFive@Screen>:
    name: 'screen five'


<PreScreenManager>:
    MySwiperManager:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id: MySwiperManager

        MDSwiperManager:
            id: swiper_manager

            ScreenOne: 

            ScreenTwo:

            ScreenThree:

            ScreenFour:

            ScreenFive:
```

Main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

from Prelogin.prescreenmanger import PreScreenManager

class MainApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
AnchorLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: "Start/Background.png"   
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'top'
    Image:
        source: 'Start/Loginlogo.png'
        keep_ratio: False
        allow_stretch: True
        opacity: 1
        size_hint: 1, 0.25
        pos_hint: (0,0)  
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        PreScreenManager:
            id: PreScreenManager
```

---

Here is an update version of the code I have. 
.py file

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.uix.managerswiper import MDSwiperPagination
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

Builder.load_file("Prelogin/prescreenmanger.kv")

class MySwiperManager(BoxLayout):
    pass

class PreScreenManager(Screen):
    swiper_manager = ObjectProperty()  # reference to MySwiperManager from kv file

    def do_setup(self, dt):
        # code to do the setup (called after App is instantiated)
        paginator = MDSwiperPagination()
        paginator.screens = self.swiper_manager.screen_names
        paginator.manager = self.swiper_manager
        self.swiper_manager.paginator = paginator
        self.swiper_manager.add_widget(paginator)
```

.kv file

```
<ScreenOne@Screen>:
    name: 'screen one'
    Label: 
        text: 'Hello World'
        color: 1,1,1

<ScreenTwo@Screen>:
    name: 'screen two'


<ScreenThree@Screen>:
    name: 'screen three'


<ScreenFour@Screen>:
    name: 'screen four'


<ScreenFive@Screen>:
    name: 'screen five'


<PreScreenManager>:
    swiper_manager: swiper_manager  # uses the id from below

    MySwiperManager:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDSwiperManager:
            id: swiper_manager

            ScreenOne:

            ScreenTwo:

            ScreenThree:

            ScreenFour:

            ScreenFive:
```

Main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

from Prelogin.prescreenmanger import PreScreenManager

class MainApp(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Indigo'
    def build(self):
        # create an instance of PreScreenManager
        psm = PreScreenManager()

        # schedule the execution of the do_setup() method
        Clock.schedule_once(psm.do_setup)

        # return the PreScreenManager instance as the root of the App display
        return psm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
AnchorLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: "Start/Background.png"   
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'top'
    Image:
        source: 'Start/Loginlogo.png'
        keep_ratio: False
        allow_stretch: True
        opacity: 1
        size_hint: 1, 0.25
        pos_hint: (0,0)  
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        PreScreenManager:
            id: PreScreenManager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I am almost understanding what you are trying to do. To get the `swiper_manager` automatically set in your `PreScreenManager`, first add the property to your `prescreenmanger.kv` file:

```
<PreScreenManager>:
    swiper_manager: swiper_manager  # uses the id from below
    my_sm: msm  # uses the id from below

    MySwiperManager:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id: msm

        MDSwiperManager:
            id: swiper_manager

            ScreenOne:

            ScreenTwo:

            ScreenThree:

            ScreenFour:

            ScreenFive:
```

I have taken the liberty to change the `id` to `msm`, because using the class name can only lead to confusion. Then, modify your `PreScreenManager` class:

```
class PreScreenManager(Screen):
    swiper_manager = ObjectProperty()  # reference to MDSwiperManager from kv file
    my_sm: ObjectProperty()  # reference to MySwiperManager from kv file

    def do_setup(self, dt):
        # code to do the setup (called after App is instantiated)
        theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Indigo'
        paginator = MDSwiperPagination()
        paginator.screens = self.swiper_manager.screen_names
        paginator.manager = self.swiper_manager
        self.swiper_manager.paginator = paginator
        self.my_sm.add_widget(paginator)
```

I have never used `kivyMD`, so I cannot vouch for the correctness of the code inside the `do_setup()` method. And, lastly, schedule the execution of the `do_setup()` method by modifying the `MainApp` class:

```
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # create an instance of PreScreenManager
        psm = PreScreenManager()

        # schedule the execution of the do_setup() method
        Clock.schedule_once(psm.do_setup)

        # return the PreScreenManager instance as the root of the App display
        return psm
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do and thank you. When I run the code you have written I get ```AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'theme_cls'``` so I added ```theme_cls = ThemeManager()
theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Indigo' ``` to the ```MainApp``` but now I get ```paginator.screens = self.swiper_manager.screen_names
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'screen_names'```

Comment: That error suggests that `swiper_manager` is not getting set. Take a close look at my answer and make sure that you have implemented my suggestions correctly. And, yes, move the `theme_cls` stuff to `MainApp`.

Comment: Yes, I was missing an import to the .kv file (That I had revomved to test if I could get it to work) but know the error message is ```AttributeError: 'MySwiperManager' object has no attribute 'screen_names'````.

Comment: I think I have solved it now maybe. I will write back when I have found out.

Comment: I see. perhaps the `swiper_manager: msm  # uses the id from below` should be `swiper_manager: swiper_manager  # uses the id from below`.

Comment: Yeah, but it still doesn't work. I just updatet the post with my current code. I now get the error  ``` 'ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.') kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.```.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use that `swiper_manager` for two different things. The  `swiper_manager: swiper_manager` sets `self.swiper_manager` to reference the `MDSwiperManager`, which is a subclass of `ScreenManager`. so it works for the line `paginator.screens = self.swiper_manager.screen_names`, but the line `self.swiper_manager.add_widget(paginator)` is trying to add the `paginator` to the `MDSwiperManager`, which can only accept `Screens`. I suspect that you actually want to add the `paginator` to your `MySwiperManager`. See my updated answer above with another `ObjectProperty()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
swiper_manager = MySwiperManager.ids.swiper_manager
```

You're confusing the class definition (`MySwiperManager`) with an *instance* of the class (e.g. `MySwiperManager()`). Usually all your code should be at instance level, putting things at class level is generally wrong, but a common mistake.

It isn't possible to give a specific solution because your example is not complete (in fact it has several other problems, always provide a minimal *runnable* example to make things easier), but the general answer is that you want to access the `ids` attribute of an instance of the `MySwiperManager` class.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just add the .py and .kv files that were missing for it to be a runnable example.